# Optimize code for step function using only NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the function 'pw' in the following code using only NumPy functions (or perhaps list comprehensions).

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

def pw(x, udata):
    """
    Creates the step function
                 | 1,  if d0 <= x < d1
                 | 2,  if d1 <= x < d2
    pw(x,data) = ...
                 | N, if d(N-1) <= x < dN
                 | 0, otherwise
    where di is the ith element in data.
    INPUT:      x   --  interval which the step function is defined over
              data  --  an ordered set of data (without repetitions)
    OUTPUT: pw_func --  an array of size x.shape[0]
    """
    vals = np.arange(1,udata.shape[0]+1).reshape(udata.shape[0],1)
    pw_func = np.sum(np.where(np.greater_equal(x,udata)*np.less(x,np.roll(udata,-1)),vals,0),axis=0)
    return pw_func


N = 50000
x = np.linspace(0,10,N)
data = [1,3,4,5,5,7]
udata = np.unique(data)

ti = time()
pw(x,udata)
tf = time()
print(tf - ti)

import cProfile
cProfile.run('pw(x,udata)')
```

The cProfile.run is telling me that most of the overhead is coming from np.where (about 1 ms) but I'd like to create faster code if possible. It seems that performing the operations row-wise versus column-wise makes some difference, unless I'm mistaken, but I think I've accounted for it. I know that sometimes list comprehensions can be faster but I couldn't figure out a faster way than what I'm doing using it.

Searchsorted seems to yield better performance but that 1 ms still remains on my computer:

```
(modified)
def pw(xx, uu):
    """
    Creates the step function
                 | 1,  if d0 <= x < d1
                 | 2,  if d1 <= x < d2
    pw(x,data) = ...
                 | N, if d(N-1) <= x < dN
                 | 0, otherwise
    where di is the ith element in data.
    INPUT:      x   --  interval which the step function is defined over
              data  --  an ordered set of data (without repetitions)
    OUTPUT: pw_func --  an array of size x.shape[0]
    """
    inds = np.searchsorted(uu, xx, side='right')
    vals = np.arange(1,uu.shape[0]+1)
    pw_func = vals[inds[inds != uu.shape[0]]]
    num_mins = np.sum(xx < np.min(uu))
    num_maxs = np.sum(xx > np.max(uu))

    pw_func = np.concatenate((np.zeros(num_mins), pw_func, np.zeros(xx.shape[0]-pw_func.shape[0]-num_mins)))
    return pw_func
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516274/step-function-with-linear-inteval-in-numpy) using piecewise seems pretty close, but that's on a scalar x0 and x1. How would I do it on arrays? And would it be more efficient?

Understandably, x may be pretty big but I'm trying to put it through a stress test.

I am still learning though so some hints or tricks that can help me out would be great.

**EDIT**

There seems to be a mistake in the second function since the resulting array from the second function doesn't match the first one (which I'm confident that it works):

```
N1 = pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1)).shape[0]
N2 = np.sum(pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1)) == pw2(x,udata))
print(N1 - N2)
```

yields

```
15000
```

data points that are *not* the same. So it seems that I don't know how to use 'searchsorted'.

**EDIT 2**

Actually I fixed it:

```
pw_func = vals[inds[inds != uu.shape[0]]]
```

was changed to

```
pw_func = vals[inds[inds[(inds != uu.shape[0])*(inds != 0)]-1]]
```

so at least the resulting arrays match. But the question still remains on whether there's a more efficient way of going about doing this.

**EDIT 3**

Thanks Tin Lai for pointing out the mistake. This one should work

```
pw_func = vals[inds[(inds != uu.shape[0])*(inds != 0)]-1]
```

Maybe a more readable way of presenting it would be

```
non_endpts = (inds != uu.shape[0])*(inds != 0) # only consider the points in between the min/max data values
shift_inds = inds[non_endpts]-1       # searchsorted side='right' includes the left end point and not right end point so a shift is needed
pw_func = vals[shift_inds]
```

I think I got lost in all those brackets! I guess that's the importance of readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very abstract yet interesting problem! Thanks for entertaining me, I had fun :)

p.s. I'm not sure about your `pw2` I wasn't able to get it output the same as `pw1`.

For reference the original `pw`s:

```py
def pw1(x, udata):
    vals = np.arange(1,udata.shape[0]+1).reshape(udata.shape[0],1)
    pw_func = np.sum(np.where(np.greater_equal(x,udata)*np.less(x,np.roll(udata,-1)),vals,0),axis=0)
    return pw_func

def pw2(xx, uu):
    inds = np.searchsorted(uu, xx, side='right')
    vals = np.arange(1,uu.shape[0]+1)
    pw_func = vals[inds[inds[(inds != uu.shape[0])*(inds != 0)]-1]]
    num_mins = np.sum(xx < np.min(uu))
    num_maxs = np.sum(xx > np.max(uu))

    pw_func = np.concatenate((np.zeros(num_mins), pw_func, np.zeros(xx.shape[0]-pw_func.shape[0]-num_mins)))
    return pw_func
```

---

My first attempt was utilising a lot of boardcasting operation from `numpy`:

```py
def pw3(x, udata):
    # the None slice is to create new axis
    step_bool = x >= udata[None,:].T

    # we exploit the fact that bools are integer value of 1s
    # skipping the last value in "data"
    step_vals = np.sum(step_bool[:-1], axis=0)

    # for the step_bool that we skipped from previous step (last index)
    # we set it to zerp so that we can negate the step_vals once we reached
    # the last value in "data"
    step_vals[step_bool[-1]] = 0

    return step_vals
```

After looking at the `searchsorted` from your `pw2` I had a new approach that utilise it with much higher performance:

```py
def pw4(x, udata):
    inds = np.searchsorted(udata, x, side='right')

    # fix-ups the last data if x is already out of range of data[-1]
    if x[-1] > udata[-1]:
        inds[inds == inds[-1]] = 0

    return inds
```

---

Plots with:

```py
plt.plot(pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1)), label='pw1')
plt.plot(pw2(x,udata), label='pw2')
plt.plot(pw3(x,udata), label='pw3')
plt.plot(pw4(x,udata), label='pw4')
```

with `data = [1,3,4,5,5,7]`:

[image]

with `data = [1,3,4,5,5,7,11]`

[image]

`pw1`,`pw3`,`pw4` are all identical

```py
print(np.all(pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1)) == pw3(x,udata)))
>>> True
print(np.all(pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1)) == pw4(x,udata)))
>>> True
```

**Performance:** (`timeit` by default runs 3 times, average of `number=N` of times)

```py
print(timeit.Timer('pw1(x,udata.reshape(udata.shape[0],1))', "from __main__ import pw1, x, udata").repeat(number=1000))
>>> [3.1938983199979702, 1.6096494779994828, 1.962694135003403]
print(timeit.Timer('pw2(x,udata)', "from __main__ import pw2, x, udata").repeat(number=1000))
>>> [0.6884554479984217, 0.6075002400029916, 0.7799002879983163]
print(timeit.Timer('pw3(x,udata)', "from __main__ import pw3, x, udata").repeat(number=1000))
>>> [0.7369808239964186, 0.7557657590004965, 0.8088172269999632]
print(timeit.Timer('pw4(x,udata)', "from __main__ import pw4, x, udata").repeat(number=1000))
>>> [0.20514375300263055, 0.20203858999957447, 0.19906871100101853]
```